# How do you disable a button inside of an AlertDialog? Follow Up Question

Tags: android

I asked this question yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392321/how-do-you-disable-a-button-inside-of-an-alertdialog) and modified my code accordingly... this morning I ran the code in an emulator and received an NPE. Here is the code:

```
public void monster() {
        int playerint = settings.getPlayerInt();
        int monsterint = settings.getMonsterInt();



        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setMessage("You have Encountered a Monster");

        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Fight!",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        createMonster();
                        fight();

                    }
                });

        alertbox.setNeutralButton("Try to Outwit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // This should not be static
//                      createTrivia();
                        trivia();

                    }
                });

        // Return to Last Saved CheckPoint
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("Run Away!",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
//                      runAway();
                    }
                });
```

***THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS***

```
// show the alert box
            alertbox.show();
            AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.create();
            Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            if(monsterint > playerint) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You have two problems.  The first is that you should be calling `show()` and `create()` separately like that.  What you've actually done is implicitly create one AlertDialog and display it with `alertbox.show()`, and then right below it create a second `AlertDialog` that you are using to manipulate the button.  Let's try to keep the direct calls to the Builder at a minimum.

Also, and the more direct reason for your NPE crash, in `AlertDialog` land the buttons themselves don't actually get created until the `AlertDialog` is prepared for display (basically, after `AlertDialog.show()` is called...again, not to be confused with the `AlertDialog.Builder.show()` method).  In order to use `AlertDialog` for your purposes, you need to obtain and manipulate the button state after displaying the dialog.  Here is a modification of your final code section that fixes this:

```
//Create the AlertDialog, and then show it
AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.create();
dialog.show();
//Button is not null after dialog.show()
Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
if(monsterint > playerint) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for you in depth answer... Unfortunately, I am still getting an NPE crash even after these modifications! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that you need to use the `AlertDialog` object retuned by `AlertDialog.Builder.show()` method. No need to call `AlertDialog.Builder.create()`.

Example:

```
        AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.show();
        if(monsterint > playerint) {
            Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

At first I thought the code should read:

```
        AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.create();
        Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        if(monsterint > playerint) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

        dialog.show();
```

And I would expect this to work, however no matter how you cook this piece of code, the call to getButton(int which) always returns null.

There doesn't seem to be any sensible reason for this.  I am tempted to say that this is a bug in the API.  I targeted it for API level 8.

**UPDATE**

Congratulations you have discovered [Android Bug #6360](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6360) see comment #4 for a workaround

Also you could take a look at a possible [indirect duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4604025/808940)

And the solution is to call getButton after `dialog.show()`:

```
        AlertDialog dialog = alertbox.create();

        dialog.show();

        Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        if(monsterint > playerint) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Comment: That's actually not true.  Calling `show()` directly on an `AlertDialog.Builder` object implicitly calls its `create()` method and then displays the result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out ... learn something new every day.  I have updated my answer

Comment: Code is still generating an NPE

Comment: @FrankBozzo I tested the code ... and it is running infront of my own eyes ... so you must have missed something.  NOTE: the correct code calls `dialog.getButton(..)` AFTER `dialog.show()`

Answer (score -1):

i tryed these code and it work's you need to hid first show ok

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertbox.setMessage("You have Encountered a Monster");
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("asdasd", null);

        alertbox.show();
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("", null);
        alertbox.show();
```

Comment: @Frank Bozzo i was just showing how to hide the button :( and i was wrong but Merlin is wrong to `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: @FrankBozzo I have updated my answer and given a complete explanation as to why this occurs